# Poker Texas Hold'em Sit-and-Go - Independent Chip Model (ICM)

Tags: poker, poker-texas-holdem

What is "ICM" in Poker Texas Hold'em?

I want to know some mathematical equations in answers on this question, because this part is important for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Independent Chip Model (ICM) is a way of calculating the right decision when playing the bubble in Texas Hold'em tournaments.

Three players:

> A = Player 1's Stack
>
> B = Player 2's Stack
>
> C = Player 3's Stack
>
> T = Total chips in play
>
> (A * 0.5 + B * (A * 0.3 + C * 0.2) / (A + C) + C * (A * 0.3 + B * 0.2) / (A + B)) / T

Comment: I had a better formula, I will edit when I find it.

Comment: what is (A * .5) ? this is equivalent to (A * 5)?

Comment: @Svisstack: It's 0.5

Comment: @aramis `(A * .5)` doesn't equal `(A * 0.1)`

Comment: (a * 0.5) = (A * (1/2)) =(A*1)/2= A/2

Answer (score 2):

ICM assumes that each player's chance to win, ability being equal or indeterminable, is proportional to his/her stack size. Chances to come in other positions can be calculated conditionally, allowing an assessment for each player of their equity at any point.

There's a reasonably good explanation (with some equations) [here](http://www.pokerjunkie.com/icm-explaining-the-independent-chip-model) and a calculator to play with [here](http://www.icmpoker.com/Calculator.aspx).